# Powershell for UI Test Automation - trying to control browser back button

Tags: powershell

I have a script to open an IE session, navigate to a URL and then click a link on that page.  I then want to return to the URL to start the test over...any suggestions for scripting the browser back button to get back to a baseline/starting point?

Comment: Can you please add some code...what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a reason to use the back button instead of just navigating to the desired URL?

Comment: Why not use a tool like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) that's built for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Use the GoBack method to automate your Internet Explorer com object.

```
$ie=New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.GoBack()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm new to Powershell and didn't realize it was that easy - thanks for your help!!!